# Data Masking in TEXT Column

Tags: user-defined-functions

I have PII element in a TEXT field that needs to be masked/scrubed in my snowflake DB. i could able to achieve this using JavaScript, need to implement the same using SQL UDF function.

EG:
I'm John, this is my SSN 111-11-1111

Output :

I'm XXXX, this is my XXX XXX-XX-XXXX

Comment: What language, DB, etc. are you talking about? There are multiple ways to mask data, I can determine your own, depending on each field.

Comment: In Snowflake using Scalar SQL UDF Function .

Comment: And did you review this already? [Using Dynamic Data Masking](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/security-column-ddm-use.html) BTW, UDF stands for User Defined Function, so it's redundant to say "function" after UDF. :P

Comment: Hi @Andrew , Yes I went through that. I shares about the masking policy. In my case I need the data to be masked as mentioned in the expected

Comment: Still there, @Naveenraj? Did you try my answer?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace any letter or digit with a `*`, I think you can use something like this:

```
case
  when current_role() in ('ADMIN') then val
  else regexp_replace(val, '[A-Za-z\d]', '*')
end;
```

More info in this article:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/security-column-ddm-use.html